# C# Передать ссылку на объект во фронт

Tags: c#, веб-программирование, объекты, azure

Учусь работать с backend в c#, использую `Azure functions` и столкнулся с такой проблемой:

При вызове определённой функции с помощью `Http` я хочу запустить асинхронный процесс, который будет выполнять определённую задачу (нейронная сеть, которая будет обучаться). Так же у меня будет вторая функция, которая может обратиться к определённому объекту нейронной сети и остановить его выполнение.

Каким образом можно передать ссылку на этот объект с помощью ответа на web request так, чтобы потом можно было обратиться к нему же?

Если есть другие варианты как это сделать - я был бы рад их услышать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете создать статическую переменную (например, `Dictionary<string, Thread>`) в которую будете сохранять свои асинхронные операции. Для передачи во фронт можете использовать ключ мапы, а при обращении с фронта - доставать из мапы свою операцию по переданному ключу.

Comment: Спасибо, думаю это рабочее решение, но звучит как оверкилл, нет ли других, более простых решений?

Comment: Других решений я сейчас не вижу. Даже если они есть, то думаю, что это самый простой из способов выполнить задачу.

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо

Comment: Если вам не нужен список асинхронных операций, то вы можете реализовать свой Singleton. Тогда не нужно передавать никаких ссылок, идентификаторов и пр. Состояние будет хранить статическое поле с единственной асинхронной операцией. И методом getInstance без параметров вы будете получать процесс.

Comment: У меня появилась проблема. 
Хорошо, я могу обратиться к Thread'у, используя определённый ключ, но как я могу обратиться к объекту, метод которого исполняется в этом Thread'e?
Возможно, вместо Thread'a я могу хранить ссылку на определённый объект?

Comment: Кажется я понял, я просто создаю объект сразу же в Dictionary. Я был бы признателен вам, если бы вы мне посоветовали, как я могу создать объект в отдельной переменной, и потом передать её **ссылку** в другую переменную (не копию), потому что у меня не получилось

Comment: Можно объявить статическую переменную и обращаться к ней из двух мест: из потока обучения и потока обработки пользовательского запроса. Но в таком случае, вы можете столкнуться с неконсистентным состоянием при чтении переменной. Т.е. напрашивается реализация Singleton паттерна, чтобы избежать возможных ошибок.